# (eevee) Lights limit?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

My question is...

How many lights (spot) can be on at the same time?

There's a limit imposed by blender or the machine specs?

Here's an example https://youtu.be/8Hjy2o3A9pg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limitations:

- Shadows are not supported on light instances (dupli objects, group
  instancing).
- Only 128 active lights can be supported by Eevee in a scene.
- Only 8 Shadowed sun lights can be supported at the same time.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/shadows.html

Comment: Do you know maybe why is that?