# hair render collection ignoring parent/child hierarchy

Tags: particles, hair

I am trying to use Particle Hair to randomly distribute houses each with a child light inside (parenting hierarchy)

[image]

Whether I use the Hair Render Object OR Collection ...

[image]

...it seems to ignore that the lights are placed relative to some position related to the interior of the house.

[image]

example file: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on "whole collection" you get this:

[image]

[image]

but i just wonder why not all house have lights!? is there something like a maximum number of lights? If i turn down the number of particles, then all houses get lights.

found it: max number of lights is 128

[(eevee) Lights limit?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129251/eevee-lights-limit)

Comment: Thanks, and the Eevee light limit has gotten me before!   Can see the warning during Show Console.